# Error: unexpected input in "colours =

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, r-sp

Hi im a real self teaching R newbie: 
I'm following a GWR tutorial [here](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/media-library/sites/cmpo/migrated/documents/gwr.pdf) 
but already on first page my code fails at

```
colours = c(“dark blue”, “blue”, “red”, “dark red”)
```

Creates a colour palette and at spplot

```
spplot(map, “Nocars”, cuts=quantile(Nocars), col.regions=colours)
```

> Error: unexpected input in "colours = c(�"

and the same for spplot

> Error: unexpected input in "spplot(Nocars, �"

Could you please help, im sure its something silly.

Comment: You are not using the right quotation marks. You use `“` and `”`, while the only ones that are permitted are `'` or `"`.

Comment: Note that this error is already in the tutorial you are using. You should look for a better tutorial.